# Ubuntu One for Android without Google Account?

Tags: ubuntu-one, android

Is there an opportunity to download and install the Ubuntu One client for Android without having a Google Account?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't the very latest version, but there is a `.apk` file for version 1.0.5.1 of the Ubuntu One Files client available here:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntuone-android-files/trunk/u1f-1.0.5.1

You should be able to install this the same way as you would any other non-market piece of software.

I don't think we've currently got policies in place to publish `.apk` files in parallel with uploads to the market at the moment.